# Node.js - are modules initialised only once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I am using node-mysql driver for a node.js app. Instead of having to set-up the mysql connection over and over again for each of my model-like modules, I do this:

```
// DB.js
var Client = require('mysql').Client;
var DB_NAME = 'test_db';
var client = new Client();
client.user = 'user';
client.password = 'pass';
client.connect();
client.query('USE '+DB_NAME);
module.exports = client;

// in User.js
var db = require("./DB");
// and make calls like:
db.query(query, callback);
```

Now, I notice that DB.js is initialised with the DB connection only once. So, subsequently the same `client` object is being used... How do I structure DB.js such that when I require it from a model, every time a new DB connection will be set-up? I know it's got something to do with using `new`, but I am not able to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
module.exports = function() {
    var client = new Client();
    client.user = 'user';
    client.password = 'pass';
    client.connect();
    client.query('USE '+DB_NAME);
    return client;
}

var db = require("./DB")()
```

Initialize a new client each time you call the database.

You could use `Object.defineProperty` to define `exports` with custom getter logic so you can do `var db = require("./DB")` if you want.

Comment: There should be a `return client;` at the end of the function. Otherwise, `db.query()` will not work.

Comment: @jeffreyveon can't believe no-one picked up such an obvouis mistake. Thanks.